# Hadoop mapreduce can't find logs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to use System.out.println in a mapreduce job to test the codes. The print out doesn't work in console, I've seen a lot other solution.

Basically ask you view the logs under the hadoop directory to see the printout, but there's no logs under my hadoop directory, and the localhost for jobtracker doesn't work. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean jobtracker doesn't work? What is the hadoop version you are working with?

Comment: Hadoop 8.0.0, when I go to the localhost:50030, nothing shown up.

Comment: what does `hadoop version` shows in the terminal? I guess you are using hadoop 2 not hadoop 1 i.e. YARN. is that so?

Comment: yea, I believe so

Comment: Then there shouldn't be jobtracker. There would be nodemanager, resourcemanager and applicationmanager. Your address to look for historyserver is wrong too. Use `localhost:19888` for historical jobs and for running jobs use `localhost:8088`. Try it and let me know